# How do you uninstall Keynote 6 but leave Keynote 5?

Tags: keynote, iwork, macos

I installed Keynote 6.x recently, and decided I want to use the old version (5.3) - commonly known as iWork '09 instead.

I have deleted 6.x Keynote using Finder, but it comes back when the App Store does software updates (which also sets *.key files to open in Keynote 6.x). I can't figure out how to get the App Store to prevent Keynote from coming back...

Comment: Since the update is free, because you have iWork '09. Each time you get an update, it will put iWork '13 back on. You have to delete it every time, or disable updates in the PrefPane.

Answer (score 3):

Open System Preferences and click on App Store

[image]

Uncheck "Install app updates" (and probably "Download newly available...")